# Error Undefined variable even if the variable is passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have the following function in the Controller:

```
public function index($id)
    {
            $client_name_tasks = Client::select('clients.name')
            ->join('projects', 'clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
            ->join('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
            ->where('tasks.project_id', $id)
            ->distinct()
            ->get();

             return view('task.index', compact('client_name_tasks'));
    }
```

where *$client_name_tasks* is collection.

Since the following view is called from different parts of my project, the title h1 is different based on where it is called (are 3 different).

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
        @isset($client_name)
            <h1>List of overall tasks of {{$client_name}}</h1> 
        @endisset
        @isset($client_name_tasks)
            @foreach($client_name_tasks as $client_name_task)
            <h1>List of {{$client_name_task->name}} project tasks</h1>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <h1>List all task</h1>
        @endisset
    </div>
```

I get error **compact(): Error $client_name_tasks**.

The problem is in the view, isset.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: I believe you need `..., compact(['tasks','client_name_tasks']));`.  It needs to be an array of names.

Comment: You have `'tasks'` in the compact call, but I don't see `$tasks` being defined anywhere.

Comment: The code you showed doesnt reflect the error you're getting, mind share the complete version of your controller method.

Comment: @N69S precisely, because isset is not read well

Comment: you need to understand how to correctly interpret isset with the other conditions

Comment: your code doesn't match the error

Answer (score 0):

You can check the count value of that collection.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
    @isset($client_name)
        <h1>List of overall tasks of {{$client_name}}</h1> 
    @endisset
    @if(count($client_name_tasks) > 0)
        @foreach($client_name_tasks as $client_name_task)
        <h1>List of {{$client_name_task->name}} project tasks</h1>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <h1>List all task</h1>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do a foreach in your controller in order to bring putting it in the compact back only the variable in the isset?

```
foreach ($client_name_tasks as $client_name_task){
           $name_client=$client_name_task->name;
}
```

and in the view write this way (attention that name_client is different from client_name):

```
        @if(isset($name_client))
            <h1>List of {{$client_name_task->name}} project tasks</h1>
        @elseif(isset($client_name))
            <h1>List of overall tasks of {{$client_name}}</h1>
        @else
            <h1>All task</h1>
        @endif
```